# How does map difficulty work in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Does it works like in Mass Effect 3 MP, where no matter how many players are in the party and their levels; or it works by changing enemies level according to the party number and party levels, like in Dead Island?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boss' health and the number of enemies per wave scale with the number of characters actively being played. You can observe this by the number of enemies next wave changing when a new player joins during build phase.

Character levels have no effect on difficulty in the game. You get the exact same enemy health and number of enemies if you're playing the same map/difficulty with a level 10 character or a level 70 character.

Comment: Yup that's why a lot of maps have a recommended level, because they don't scale to your current one.